# Select a value from a variable

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

In Extjs, I am trying to select a value `accrued` from a variable `Store`.

[image]

I tried:

```
var newStore = Store.data.items[0].data.accrued;
```

The above one is not working. I am getting error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined

Whenever I add `items[0]`, it is making the variable undefined.

When I checked:

```
var newStore = Store.data.items.length;
```

output is: **0**  //?

But I can see that there are items in `Store` variable here as shown in the above image. Anyway, I just want to get the value of `accrued` from the variable `Store`.

I also checked:

```
var newStore = Store.data.items;
```

output is: **[ ]**

Comment: Store or store ? The first one with a up-cased 'S'.

Comment: Sorry it was typo. it's `Store` @JinzhaoWu

Comment: Try `for(x in Store.data.items) console.log(x);` to make sure the index is indeed `0` ?

Comment: @techfoobar It is not showing anything because `Store.data.items` is **[ ]** (I don't know how).

Comment: I don't know if this will be helpful but try this `Ext.getStore('store_id').data.items[0].data.accrued`

Comment: @cclerville same problem.. Thanks though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey Mr_Green you should look into the API sometimes, cause this is really straight forward ;) **[Store load event](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-load)**

```
Store.on('load', function(store,records){ 
    records[0].data.accrued; 
}, this, {single:true})
```

***Update - a bit more in depth***

The tiny word **[on](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-on)** applies a listener for a event to a component. It will be available for classes that mixin **[Ext.util.Observable](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable)** where the last argument I applied identifies that this listener should get removed after it get called once. This is useful for anonymous listeners cause you cannot unregister them otherwise.

*load( this, records, successful, eOpts )*

**Parameters**

- this : **Ext.data.Store**
- records : **Ext.data.Model[]** *An array of records*
- successful : **Boolean** *True if the operation was successful.*
- eOpts : **Object** *The options object passed to Ext.util.Observable.addListener.*

So the records argument contains all the records that are returned by the current load operation.

Comment: I kept console.log() to the generated variable and checked the variable value. It is showing `undefined`. (I still can't understand what you did here, I am working on it)

Comment: Hey its `records[0].data.accrued`. :). Please update it. working fine now. Thanks +1.

Comment: @Mr_Green My mistake, sorry. I also extended the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Store loading is asynchronous. When you are logging, the values aren't loaded yet.

The console always shows the most up to date version of the object. You need to listen to the store load event.

Comment: Thanks for response. Can you please explain me how to do that?