# change the html from controller in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

In my Extjs 4.1.1a project,

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cuJ5S/4/)** (*this fiddle is not working, it is just for reference*)

I am changing the HTML(In controller) value using

```
Ext.apply(weekNotifications,{html: {"hello"});
```

But the page(view) is not updating. When I checked the variable `weekNotifications` in Chrome console, after the above function, the `innerHTML` is "hello" as I added but in `weekNotifications.el.dom.innerHTML` is "Notifications here" (old text).

I even tried:

```
weekNotifications.update("Hello");   //same problem as stated above
```

When I tried:

```
weekNotifications.el.dom.innerHTML = "hello";
```

I am getting error - Cannot call dom of undefined

For better understanding, I am pasting the images of `console.log(weekNotifications)`

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I am getting `weekNotifications` variable by doing `ComponentQuery`.

Comment: Then you're getting a reference to the wrong thing. `update` is the correct method to use.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I did `weekNotification.update("hello")` still the html is same old text. though the innerHTML is changing as I posted above as image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the variable `weekNotification` was not rendered when I was trying to change the html. So I did the following which worked for me:

```
weekNotifications.on(
      'render',
      function(self){
         self.update("hello");
      },
      this
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment, you're getting a reference to the wrong component somehow. `update` is the correct method to use:

```
Ext.require('*');

Ext.onReady(function() {

    var ct = new Ext.container.Container({
        renderTo: document.body,
        html: 'Foo'
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        ct.update('Bar');
    }, 500);

});
```

Comment: As always, I think I done something wrong then. I am getting variable by doing this `var weekNotifications = Ext.getCmp('compIdHere').query('container>container')[1]`. Is there anything wrong in it? Please response, I wasted lot of time on it.

Comment: Well... it's sort of an odd query. You said get all the containers that are a direct child of a container that are inside `notificationViewInner` and get the item at the 2nd index in the array.

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant. all other index value components are working well. (means not changing html but adding dynamic child items to them)

Comment: Well, it's not the one you're looking for, otherwise it would be updated. If you can put together a small working test case I'll look at it, otherwise it's just speculating about what might be in your code. Also, by putting together a test case you'll likely figure it out yourself.

Comment: Here is the [link to the view of my page](https://gist.github.com/venkateshwar/db5d34a00e911dccfc72). I am trying to create a fiddle now which not happening(I don't know why)

Comment: I created the fiddle, but it is not working. please check. http://jsfiddle.net/cuJ5S/1/. I hope this you can understand. Please help.

Comment: Yes but that is what I have implemented in my code.  (I tried adding `renderTo: Ext.getBody()` to make it work in fiddle, but no use). This is working good in my project.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better not to bypass the ExtJS component update mechanism using `innerHTML`, this will be confusing. That said, note that you confuse two different properties which have effectively the same name (innerHTML) but are owned by objects of different types. The one you have underlined in the first picture is not owned by a native DOM node as you seem to believe, the owner is actually an ExtJS object (take a look at the "xtype" property). This means that your are not interacting with a DOM object, so, updating its innerHTML property produces nothing.

Comment: Then please tell me how to change the html ? Here I am getting the variable through `ComponentQuery`.

Comment: @Mr_Green Please simplify your jsFiddle example.

Comment: That is my complete code in my project. It is not working in fiddle. (I don't know why).

Comment: @Mr_Green Try to shorten your jsFiddle code. Trust me, it's good way to isolate the origin of the problem - and to take care of our eyes :)

Comment: I made it smaller, you can understand it but can't run it. http://jsfiddle.net/cuJ5S/2/

Comment: wared, That code is just for reference. I have no typos in my code. Anyway, I update my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cuJ5S/4/

Comment: wared, It was simple error. The container which I was calling was not rendered. so, I just called `weekNotifications.on('render',function(){},this);` .this worked :)

Comment: In my point of view you didn't provide sufficient efforts to guide us.

Comment: But I just explained how I am getting the variable (`ComponentQuery`) and how I am trying to change the html. and also what efforts I did to try to change the html. I even provided you the full code fiddle(which was somehow not working, unfortunately). Anyway, Its alright. I added the answer to this post. and also in my opinion, one couldn't have expected this kind of solution. (which did by [evan trimboli in one of the previous posts](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15378750/1577396), which I thought that it is only for **stores**)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing the html after render of the component(it ensures that the html is ready for using or making changes).like below

```
Ext.require('*');

Ext.onReady(function() {

var ct = new Ext.container.Container({
    renderTo: document.body,
    html: 'Foo',
    listeners:{
        afterrender:function(ct){
            ct.el.dom.innerHTML = "hello"; //works
           // ct.update('Bar');  //works
        }
    }
});
```

});